# Sitecore Powershell Script to find all the items with Personalizations defined

Tags: powershell-extensions

I need to find all the items that has personalization defined on the layout definitions using a Sitecore Powershell Extensions script.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

If personalisation is enabled for an item, then there will be a parameter named rules, when we get the rendering using "Get-Rendering". The same can be done for a parent item and run the code for child items which has Rules in its renderings.

I have made a code snippet that will get all the items that has personalization defined

```
function GetPersonalization($item)    
{
    $count = 0
    $renderingInstance = Get-Rendering -Item $item
    $renderingInstance | ForEach-Object {
        if($_.Rules)
        {
            $count++
        }
    }
    if($count -gt 0)
    {
        return $item
    }
}

$itempath = "/sitecore/content/home/test"
$AllItems = Get-ChildItem -Path $itempath -Recurse
$table = @()
$AllItems | ForEach-Object {
    $table += GetPersonalization -item $_
}

$table | Show-ListView -Property `
   @{ Name="Item Name"; Expression={$_.DisplayName}},
   @{ Name="Item path"; Expression={$_.FullPath}}
```

Answer (score 7):

You can run fast query and check if __renderings field contains `conditions` or `rule` nodes:

```
$query = "fast:/sitecore//*[@__renderings='%<conditions%' or @#__Final Renderings#='%<conditions%']"
Get-Item -Path "master:" -Query $query
```

Comment: Might shave off a few seconds if you narrow it down to sitecore/content.

Answer (score 7):

If you combine the answer from @Anton and @Sreekrishnan you get a nice and fast report.

```powershell
$query = "fast:/sitecore/content//*[@__renderings='%<conditions%' or @#__Final Renderings#='%<conditions%']"
$items = Get-Item -Path "master:" -Query $query
$items | Show-ListView -Property `
   @{ Name="Item Name"; Expression={$_.DisplayName}},
   @{ Name="Item path"; Expression={$_.FullPath}}
```

[image]